# Increasing incrementally until a value is reached

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to display a value by increasing it incrementally until the desired value is reached.

I have tried two ways of doing it and neither works.

```
def temperature_gauge(self):
    self.dT = self.dU.get() / (float(self.entry_m.get()) * float(self.entry_Cv.get()))
    self.counter = 0
    while self.counter >= 0:
        self.c.delete(self.L2)
        self.L2 = self.c.create_text(90,345, text=self.counter)
        self.c.update()
        self.counter += 1.00
        if self.counter == float(self.dT):
            break

def temperature_gauge(self):
    self.dT = self.dU.get() / (float(self.entry_m.get()) * float(self.entry_Cv.get()))
    self.counter = 0
    for i in range(0, int(self.dT)):
        self.number_text = self.c.create_text(90,345, text=(i))
        self.c.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.c.delete(self.number_text)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  Specifically, this question has a fair amount unexplained problem domain specifics, and it does not detail what you mean by *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Fix slightly awkward wording.